# Angular: Not able to reuse the same component for multiple forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, formarray

I am trying to reuse an existing component in a single page where I am required to display multiple forms on the same page based on the no of users. For example if I have 10 users then I should have 10 address forms and map them to the appropriate user. I tried many ways but not able to get there. I understand that I may have to use a formarray to achieve this I just don't know how.

Here's my code:

```
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted))
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'rms-address',
  templateUrl: './address.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddressComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddressComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class AddressComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy {
  name: String
  abbreviation: string
  @Input() address: Address
  @Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<Address>();
  selectedClass: any
  subscriptions: Subscription[] = []

  addressForm = this.fb.group({
    addressLine1: ['', Validators.required],
    addressLine2: [''],
    city: ['', Validators.required],
    state: ['', Validators.required],
    zipCode: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[ 0-9]*$')]],
  })

  get value(): Address {
    return this.addressForm.value
  }

  set value(value: Address) {
    this.addressForm.setValue(value)
    this.onChange(value)
    this.onTouched()
  }

  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher()

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.selectedClass = Constants
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.addressForm.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
        this.onChange(value)
        this.onTouched()
      })
    )
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newItemEvent.emit();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach((s) => s.unsubscribe())
  }

  onChange: any = () => { }
  onTouched: any = () => { }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    if (value) {
      this.value = value
    }

    if (value === null) {
      this.addressForm.reset()
    }
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn
  }
  validate(_: FormControl) {
    return this.addressForm.valid ? null : { address: { valid: false } }
  }
}
```

address.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="addressForm" class="address-form">
  <mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <mat-label>Address 1</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput formControlName="addressLine1" required [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" />
    <mat-error *ngIf="addressForm.hasError('addressLine1') && !addressForm.hasError('required')">
      Please enter a valid address
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="addressForm.get('addressLine1').hasError('required')">
      Address 1 is required
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <mat-label>Address 2</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput formControlName="addressLine2" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" />
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <mat-label>City</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput formControlName="city" required [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" />
    <mat-error *ngIf="addressForm.get('city').hasError('required')">
      City is required
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <table class="full-width" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>State</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="state" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let state of selectedClass.USStates" [(value)]="state.key">
              {{ state.key }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
          <mat-error *ngIf="addressForm.get('state').hasError('required')">Please choose a valid state </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field class="full-width">
          <mat-label>ZIP</mat-label>
          <input type="text" matInput formControlName="zipCode" required maxlength="5" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" />
          <mat-error *ngIf="addressForm.get('zipCode').hasError('required')">
            Zipcode is required
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error
            *ngIf="addressForm.get('zipCode').hasError('pattern') && !addressForm.get('zipCode').hasError('required')">
            Please enter a valid zipcode
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

user-address.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="userAddressForm">
                <div *ngIf="!isSameAddress">
                    <ul class="list-group padding renewal-list">
                        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of users">
                            <div class="card address-card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                        <rms-address formControlName="registeredAddress">
                                        </rms-address>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr class="horizontal-line" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="isSameAddress">
                    <rms-address formControlName="sameRegisteredAddress"></rms-address>
                </div>
            </form>
```

user-address.component.ts:

```
export class UserAddressComponent implements OnInit {
  users: Users[]
  isSameAddress: boolean = false
  @Input() data: any

  changeOfAddressForm = this.fb.group({
    registeredAddress: this.fb.array([]),
    sameRegisteredAddress: [],
    isSameAddress: [false]
  })
}
```